# Is the AMD A6-6400k APU comparable to the NVidia GTX 480 Graphics Card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, compatibility

My PC build has an AMD A6-6400k APU instead of a graphics card. A game I'm planning to buy has a minimum requirement for the NVidia GTX 480. Will I be able to run it, assuming that I meet all other requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrated graphics on this processor is the [Radeon HD 8470D](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-A6-Series%20A6-6400K.html).

[Comparing benchmarks](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-480-vs-AMD-Radeon-HD-8470D/3157vsm9693) between these two GPUs, there is a *huge* difference in performance favouring the GTX 480, to the point they are practically incomparable in terms of performance. As such, I would suggest your machine will struggle to play the game in question, if it can at all.

As a *very general rule*, a dedicated graphics card such as the GTX480 will outperform most integrated graphics. Integrated graphics is usually enough to process video and general use, but is rarely powerful enough to handle any high end gaming.

Your machine may have capacity to add a PCI-e graphics card. If so, even a fairly cheap one would provide a far better gaming experience than your integrated GPU. I would recommend looking at what is available and checking online for various benchmarks, ideally for the actual game you are looking to get.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sadly, It will be at least 8-10 months before I can afford a graphics card comparable to the GTX 480.

Comment: @ZeroBitsRBX Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :(

Comment: If I put in some extra work time, maybe I can upgrade some time in June, around the same time the game is released.